WAL file lifecycle and standby promotion
I'm encountering difficulties automating Postgres 12 standby promotion. I've noticed that Postgres typically writes and archives a .partial WAL (Write-Ahead Log) file upon promotion, but there's one database where this behavior isn't observed.
My understanding is that the .partial file is created when XLogArchiveIsReadyOrDone(origfname) returns false. This condition occurs when either a .partial.done or .partial.ready file is absent from archive_status dir. Could someone clarify what this signifies exactly? And what is the lifecycle of a WAL file in such cases?
